# Usage of The word "Disagree"

Tags: american-english, commas

> And there are enough differences of views between Trump and Republicans, among them[,] the vice-president elect, for Congress and the president to disagree.

<sup>([What will Trump’s foreign policy look like?](http://theconversation.com/what-will-trumps-foreign-policy-look-like-68731), *The Conversation*)</sup>

In this sentence, does Congress disagree with the president or do Congress and the President disagree about the same thing together?

Comment: Although context is not always necessary, it would have made it easier to explain the answer to you with the context. http://theconversation.com/what-will-trumps-foreign-policy-look-like-68731

Comment: "And there are enough differences of views between Trump and Republicans, among them[,] the vice-president elect, for Congress and the president to [be in disagreement]." Does this help?

Comment: 谢谢黄老师！ 后面的这个president 是奥巴马还是川普呀？

Comment: "And there are enough differences of views between Trump and Republicans, among them[,] the vice-president elect, for Congress and [Trump] to [be in disagreement]."

Answer (score 2):

If I were to come across this sentence, I'd assume the former — that Congress is in disagreement with the President — given the context. The reader is told that Mr. Trump and Republicans see enough things differently for this to be possible.

That being said, I'm not particularly a fan of the sentence. *Include* should most definitely be *including*, and I believe "differences *in* views" is more standard than "differences *of* views," for future reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help !  I have another sentence like " it is unusual for you and Tom to disagree,.  in this sentence , you disagree with Tom or you and Tom disagree with an opinion or something together ?  Thanks again !!!

Comment: In Britain *differences of view(s)* would predominate over *differences in view(s)*. Clearly it takes two people to disagree. but the verb can be rendered as *I disagree with...* or as *we disagree about...*.