# The intransitive word "disagree"

Tags: sentence-meaning, transitivity

The word "disagree" is intransitive so why in this sentence

> *It is unusual for you and Tom to disagree*"

is there no "with" or "upon" to follow it?

Is its meaning the same as "It is unusual for you and Tom to disagree with each other"?

Comment: It's entirely a matter of *context*. The speaker might mean she rarely finds that you and Tom disagree with each other, but she *might* mean the two of you rarely disagree with *her* (or even, rarely disagree with *anyone, in any situation*).

Comment: Thanks for your kind help !                                                                                   what does this sentence mean ,  " There are enough differences in views between Trump and Republicans for Congress and the president to disagree."  it means Congress will disagree with the president over something or Congress and President will have same stand to be against the something?

Comment: I *think* you're right that ***disagree*** is always intransitive for most people, but no-one would have a problem with transitive *We **agreed the price** before he started work*. And exactly the same ambiguity would be there in your example if you changed ***disagree*** to ***agree*** (or ***argue***, or any other verb that *could* apply to an "object phrase", regardless of whether it would require a preposition or not).

Comment: so it needs context to figure out  right ?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't agree on "We agreed the price before he started work.", but "We agreed the price was acceptable." would be OK, though still the meaning really is "We agreed on the price."

Comment: @user3169    I am confused by you both , could  you please explain more , thank you so much !

Comment: @user3169  We agreed THAT the price was acceptable , right

Comment: @user3169 Thanks for your kind help ! what does this sentence mean , " There are enough differences in views between Trump and Republicans for Congress and the president to disagree." it means Congress will disagree with the president over something or Congress and President will have same stand to be against the something?

Comment: @user3169: I don't think this is a case where we can just agree to differ. Google Books claims almost 50,000 written instances of [agreed the terms](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22agreed+the+terms%22), of which almost all will be fully transitive usages (unlike your example, where *the price was acceptable* is a ***statement*** with preceding ***that*** deleted, as opposed to a ***noun phrase*** acting as the object of a transitive verb).

Comment: @user186904: Because the *majority* of congressmen are Republicans, if a lot of Republicans hold views different to Trump's, there will probably be some "formal disagreements" between Congress and the President (i.e. - Congress won't always vote the way the President wants them to).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks !  in the sentence the president is Trump , not Obama  right ?

Comment: @user186904: You got it. The sentence shows a common kind of "symmetry" in that the first pair of noun phrases *(Trump, Republicans)* are ***both*** replaced by contextually-equivalent *President, Congress* when they're alluded to the second time. It's irrelevant that *strictly speaking* Trump isn't President ***yet***, and Congress isn't ***completely*** Republican.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Intransitive verbs do not need an object, so why do you need a "with" or "upon"? Intransitive verbs can exist *without* objects and in fact, this is [one of their hallmarks](http://speakspeak.com/grammar-articles/transitive-and-intransitive-verbs).

Answer (score 1):

Intransitive verbs do not automatically require any *with*, *upon* or other type of complement.  If the additional information is needed, it can be expressed.  If it is not needed, it can be omitted.

> It is unusual for you and Tom to disagree.

One of two things are happening here:

- The speaker/writer is assuming the listener/reader already knows what you and Tom are disagreeing about.
- This sentence can also mean the same as "It is unusual for you and Tom to disagree on anything" or "It is unusual for you and Tom to disagree in general."

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being wrong, I have to say I do not understand your own question.

Because disagree is an intransitive verb, it *does not* need an object, and therefore, does not need "with" or "upon" to follow it.

So, I'm not sure why you want to force it to have one.

The reason "with" or "upon" follow "disagree" at times is because of the object, not the verb.

Does this help?

Comment: It is unusual for you and Tom to disagree. 这个句子我看不懂 为什么是You and Tom 彼此之间有分歧呢？ 为什么不是You and Tom 都不同意某一件事，他们两个一起不同意某一件事或者某一个看法。**又比如** _There are enough differences in views between Trump and Republicans for Congress and the president to disagree._ 这句话，为什么是国会和总统之间有分歧，而不是国会和总统都不同意something，另外 这个总统是Obama 还是Trump 呀？ 谢谢黄老师！

Comment: @SteveChoi Do you have some context? Where did the Tom sentence come from?

Comment: @SteveChoi Do you still need an answer for the Trump and Republicans sentence? I noticed you got it answered here [already](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114756/the-word-disagree-usage).

Comment: Yes , I need more clear explain , thanks so much Ms Huang !

Comment: @SteveChoi I've responded on the question's page [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114756/the-word-disagree-usage).

Answer (score 0):

If the subject of the verb *disagree* is both people, than it means they have different opinions:

> Bob and I disagree on this matter.

If the subject is only one party, than you use *with* to link another party who the subject disagrees with:

> I disagree with Bob on this matter.

In your question, the actor is both "you" and Tom, so the sentence is correct. It can be reworded, though:

> It is unusual for **you** to disagree **with** Tom.

As for *upon*, it is intended to explain further and introduce the matter people disagree on. If you are not talking about a particular matter and want to say that people just often argue (or if the matter is clear from the context), then no *upon/on* is needed.

Keep in mind that such constructions are possible:

> *Bob and I disagree with Tom.*